# Decoding transaction data using abi-decoder

Tags: abi, typescript, decoding

I'm trying to write a very simple script in typescript that finds uniswap transactions and decodes the transaction data so I can read the function being called and the parameters it is being called with. After some initial research I found that [this package seems to be the most up to date project I could find to accomplish this.](https://github.com/sambacha/abi-decoder) However I found that I am running into this error when trying to use the package.

```
 error TS2345: Argument of type '({ inputs: { internalType: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; stateMutability: string; type: string; name?: undefined; outputs?: undefined; } | { inputs: { internalType: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; name: string; outputs: { ...; }[]; stateMutability: string; type: string; } | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Item[]'.
  Type '{ inputs: { internalType: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; stateMutability: string; type: string; name?: undefined; outputs?: undefined; } | { inputs: { internalType: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; name: string; outputs: { ...; }[]; stateMutability: string; type: string; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'Item'.
    Type '{ inputs: { internalType: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; stateMutability: string; type: string; name?: undefined; outputs?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Item'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type'.

994 addABI(uniswapV2ABI);
     

  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Obviously it's a type mismatch but I'm not sure what I should be doing differently other than just require the ABI. If I look at [the test file for this project](https://github.com/sambacha/abi-decoder/blob/master/test/test.js#L10) or the one its forked from, or other projects that I have seen, they normally do something like this:

```
const uniswapV2ABI = require('./abis/uniswap_v2.abi')
```

and then proceed to use the imported ABI. Does anyone have any suggestions for what I should be doing differently? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full code I've written:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { UNISWAP_ADDRESS } from "./constants"

import { addABI, decodeMethod } from "abi-decoder-ts"



const uniswapV2ABI = require('./abis/uniswap_v2.abi')

addABI(uniswapV2ABI);



const web3 = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(NODE_ADDR);

async function connect(){
    console.log("Connecting to node...")
    await web3.ready;
    console.log("Node connected");
    return;
}

async function nodeStats(){
    const blockNum = await web3.getBlockNumber();
    console.log("Current Block Height:\t" + blockNum)
}

connect();
nodeStats();


let mempool = [ ];
web3.on("pending", async function(tx) {
    // mempool.push(tx);
    let transaction = await web3.getTransaction(tx)
    try{
        if(UNISWAP_ADDRESS === transaction.to.toLowerCase()){
            console.log("Found New Uniswap Transaction:")
            console.log(transaction.data)
            // const decodedData = decodeMethod(transaction.data);
            // console.log(decodedData)
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }catch{
        return;

    }

});
```